# How to open several active terminals with perl

Tags: perl, terminal

In my Perl script I need to open several terminals at the same time which will all be actively outputting information.

I can use the `system` function to run one terminal but the problem is that the script then waits for that terminal to finish executing before moving on and opening the next terminal whereas I need every terminal to be running concurrently and not consecutively.

Comment: Which OS? ? ? ?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add "&" at the end of the call to not wait for the process to complete. e.g.

```
system "get_mail &";
```

More information can be found [Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=22764)

EDIT:
After understanding what exactly you want, try this command:

```
system("gnome-terminal -e yourcommand &");
```

This will create a new terminal and run the command given. You can use this as many times to create as many windows you wish.

Depending on your OS you may need to change 'gnome-terminal' to what is needed.

Comment: This does allow me to run more code before a terminal command has finished but I still need to be able to run each command in its own separate terminal